Mockito the purpose of the eq() API?
I’m starting to learn Mockito using Kotlin, and I’m a bit confused about the eq() API.
I’ve noticed that whether I use eq() or not, the following test still PASSES:
@Test
fun init_shouldShowLoading() {
    viewModel.initGame()
    verify(loadingObserver).onChanged(eq(true))
}

What is the difference between using eq() and not using it? When should I use eq()? Thank you so much!

If you only use the eq matcher, it doesn't matter, but if you need to match arguments with different matchers, you need to provide matchers for all arguments.
This works:
verify(someMock).someMethod(eq("param1"), eq("param2"))

and so does this:
verify(someMock).someMethod(eq("param1"), anyString())

but this does not:
verify(someMock).someMethod("param1", anyString())

This is explicitly covered in the Mockito docs on argument matchers:

Warning on argument matchers:
If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
The following example shows verification but the same applies to stubbing:
verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), eq("third argument"));
//above is correct - eq() is also an argument matcher

verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), "third argument");
//above is incorrect - exception will be thrown because third argument is given without an argument matcher.



so my above test init_shouldShowLoading() no need to use the eq()? thank you

@soiXam if all your parameters are literal values, then you don't need eq (but it doesn't hurt either)
